# Mongodb: select all the fields in the document with few fields' value set conditionally

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

We have a collection named `product` which stores products of different types (for ex. electronics, food, footwears etc.) having different defining properties for them. The use case is, we want to select all the fields returned in response for a particular product without defining them in `select` with `find` or `project` with `aggregate`. Reason for this is, the products are completely of varying types and we won't be knowing which fields to select. For example - an electronic product would have size in inches while a food product will be having manufacturing date and expiry date. All we want is, select all the fields that are there in the document with some condition on some generic fields as - tax, gtin etc.

Problem is, with find I can only select or deselect fields without adding any condition and with aggregate I will have to mention each field in project that is needed in the response and I don't know field names beforehand.

This is the generic product schema which is applicable to every product:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: [true, 'Product name is required.'] },
  product_type: String,
  description: String,
  company: String,
  gtin: String,
  tax: Number,
  price: Number
}, {strict: false});
```

For these two product documents:

```
[{
    "name": "Coca-Cola Soft Drink, 2L PET Bottle",
    "product_type": "Beverages",
    "description": "The original cola flavoured refreshment to be enjoyed with loved ones",
    "company": "Coca-Cola",
    "gtin": "74125896352SDSFEED343", 
    "price": 83,
    "package_weight": "2.14 Kg"
},
{
    "name": "Lenovo X1 Titanium Yoga (Intel)",
    "product_type": "Electronics",
    "description": "Lenovo X1 Titanium Yoga (Intel)",
    "company": "Lenovo",
    "price": 50000,
    "tax": 5,
    "screen_size": "14 inches",
    "operating_system": "Windows 10 Pro"
}]
```

Expected output is:

```
[{
    "name": "Coca-Cola Soft Drink, 2L PET Bottle",
    "product_type": "Beverages",
    "description": "The original cola flavoured refreshment to be enjoyed with loved ones",
    "company": "Coca-Cola",
    "gtin": "74125896352SDSFEED343", 
    "price": 83,
    "tax": 0,
    "package_weight": "2.14 Kg"
},
{
    "name": "Lenovo X1 Titanium Yoga (Intel)",
    "product_type": "Electronics",
    "description": "Lenovo X1 Titanium Yoga (Intel)",
    "company": "Lenovo",
    "gtin": null,
    "price": 50000,
    "tax": 5,
    "screen_size": "14 inches",
    "operating_system": "Windows 10 Pro"
}]
```

i.e. If there is no tax or gtin defined for a product the response must have tax as 0 and gtin as null returned along with all the fields present in the document.

Comment: have you tried aggregation with `$set` or `$addFields`?

Comment: @Joe No, I have not. I am giving it a try now. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Joe This is solving my problem when I am using it in aggregate for fetching a particular product or all of the products. But, with search aggregation it is not. I need searchScore as well in the response. It is returning results with gtin null and tax 0 when not present but not searchScore as I have removed project in that case.

Comment: This is my search query for aggregation: `{ $search: { text: { query: search_string, path: search_path, fuzzy: { maxEdits: 2} } } }, { $set: {  "gtin": {$ifNull: ["$gtin", null]}, "domain":  { $ifNull: ["$domain", null] }, "tax": { $ifNull: ["$tax", 0] } } } ]; ` If I use project here for fetching searchScore along, I will have to mention field names and if I don't use project will not be getting searchScore with results.

Comment: Are you sure you can't get searchScore in $set?

Comment: @Joe Thank you. I didn't know searchScore can work with `set` as well. Now, my updated query looks like `{ $search: { text: { query: search_string, path: search_path, fuzzy: { maxEdits: 2} } } }, { $set: {  "gtin": {$ifNull: ["$gtin", null]}, "domain":  { $ifNull: ["$domain", null] }, "tax": { $ifNull: ["$tax", 0] }, score: { $meta: "searchScore" } } } ];` and is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have solved all the three use cases of mine with the suggestion given by @Joe. Here I am posting queries formed for fetching the desired results (i.e. Adding some generic fields to product documents with default values if the fields are not present in any of the document along with the varying fields present in the document).

**1. To fetch all the documents**

```
[{ 
    $set: {  
        "gtin": {$ifNull: ["$gtin", null]},
        "domain":  { $ifNull: ["$domain", null] },
        "tax": { $ifNull: ["$tax", 0] } 
    } 
}];
```

**2. To fetch a particular document by matching a condition**

```
[{
    "$match":{"_id":"60f668ccadb9e9147ed8a8ec"}
 },
 { 
     $set: {  
        "gtin": {$ifNull: ["$gtin", null]},
        "domain":  { $ifNull: ["$domain", null] },
        "tax": { $ifNull: ["$tax", 0] } 
     } 
 }];
```

**3. To apply search and fetch desired result**

```
[   
    { 
        $search: { 
            text: { 
               query: <STRING_TO_SEARCH>,
               path: <PATH_TO_LOOK_IN>, 
               fuzzy: { maxEdits: 2} 
            } 
        } 
    },
    { 
        $set: {
            "gtin": {$ifNull: ["$gtin", null]},
            "domain":  { $ifNull: ["$domain", null] }, 
            "tax": { $ifNull: ["$tax", 0] }, 
             score: { $meta: "searchScore" } 
        } 
    }
];
```